# AD Group authorization not working in IIS in Blazor Server application

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, blazor

My AD Group authorization works perfectly in my development environment but when I publish to IIS it does not. The authentication works there though and I can see when I go to my site that I am the authenticated user but it is as if I am not in any of the groups, I am using to authorize parts of my application.

This looks like a configuration issue on the IIS.

Does anyone have an idea about what can be done here?

Comment: I sometimes make a page called Claims.razor based on this page to see what happening re roles and claims -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1. It might be useful in confirming your suspicions.

Comment: Can you share your Claims.razor code?

Comment: https://github.com/BrianLParker/RoleBaseAuth/blob/master/RoleBaseAuth/Client/Pages/Claims.razor

Comment: Thanks - I found this to make this readable:

@foreach (var claim in _claims)
    {
        string adGroup = "";
        try
        {
            adGroup = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($"{claim.Value}").Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
        }
        catch{}
        <li>@adGroup</li>
     }

Comment: As it turns out - on the IIS server I actually am in the groups I should be in but authorization still fails there but it passes on my machine. A little bit of a mystery!

Comment: I had a similar issue. In my case it appears to be [due to long polling](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17467).

Comment: You were right @d_ugRiddle - the isse is related to long polling. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @d_ugRiddle pointed out my problem has to do with long polling. In my case it got fixed by installing WebSocet Protocol:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket

... on the IIS machine. It looks like the application falls back to long polling if WebSocket protocol is not installed with these consequences I described.

Comment: Please mark the answer  so that it can help others with similar problems